# Unhandled exception type IOEsxception using ApacheCommnonsIO's method

Tags: java, eclipse, ioexception, unhandled

I am trying to use copyDirectory() method from ApacheCommnonsIO package.

My code is:

**First Class**

```
import java.io.*;
import org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils;
public class ClassN1{
 public static methodThatUsesCPDIRMethod(){
  String src = "/home/user/dir_src";
  String dst = "/home/user/dir_dst";
  try {
   FileUtils.copyDirectory(new File(src), new File(dst));
  } catch (IOException e){  }
 }
```

**Second class**

```
public class ClassN2{
 public ClassN2(){
  ClassN1.methodThatUsesCPDIRMethod();
 }
}
```

**Main method**

```
public class Main{
 public static void main(String[] args){
  ClassN2 obj = new ClassN2();
 }
```

}

Is just an example, in code I haven't syntax errors, that can be there.

Problem: the ClassN1.methodThatUsesCPDIRMethod() in second's class constructor is highlighted with an error:

```
  Unhandled exception type IOEsxception
```

I use VIM + Eclim plugin (Eclipse)

Comment: This is odd. If `ClassN1.methodThatUsesCPDIRMethod()` does not declare itself as `throws IOException` and the invokation in `ClassN2` c'tor is indeed that simple (and `ClassN2` extends `Object`, and not other class) - I'd try to clean the environment and retry - maybe it's the issue. If one of the things I mentioned earlier is true - please elaborate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did not check this, but it looks like the FileUtils are throwing this IOEsxception (interesting spelling!?) which your class don't catch. In this case you have to either add this exception to the method (the c'tor in your case) or you change the catch statement to catch the exception too.

```
    try {
   FileUtils.copyDirectory(new File(src), new File(dst));
  } catch (Exception e){ //Please log at least a message here!!! }
```

Comment: but `methodThatUsesCPDIRMethod()` does not declare itself as `throws IOException` - thus the compile error should have been within `ClassN1` according to this approach.

Comment: Thank you! Also I added try..catch block to Class2 constructor, and it works. Yes, spelling isn't correct: English is not my native language :)